# why dynamically added user control's button event not getting fired?

Tags: asp.net

I have loading a -user control dynamically it has got some submit button code, the usercontrol get successfully registered at run time, but do not fire it's submit button event on button click, what i am missing would any body tell me on this?

see here is my code

```
 switch (ContentTypeID)
        {
            case 1:
                myCtrl = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/DocumentSpreadSheet.ascx");

                if (myCtrl != null)
                {
                    ((Controls_DocumentSpreadSheet)myCtrl).ddlList = int.Parse(ddlList.SelectedValue);
                    pnlDetails.Controls.Add(myCtrl);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
```

now the user control being registered at run time has some button which has the following event

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkRequiredFields(true) == true)
        {
            saveContentDetails();
            btnCancel_Click(null, null);
            //   loadSummaryGrid(true);
        }
        else
        {
            showMessageBox("Invalid data; please correct all errors.");
        }

    }
```

this event not getting fired, i have attached the break point and observed it.

rendered mark up

```
<div id="MainContent_ctl00_divButtons">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 97%;
        margin: 10px;" id="Table3">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="4">
                <input type="image" src="../images/submit_btn.png" id="MainContent_ctl00_btnInsert" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$btnInsert">
                &nbsp;
                <input type="image" src="../images/cancel-btn.png" id="MainContent_ctl00_btnCancel" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$btnCancel">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

the actual mark up

Comment: Unfortunately all the psychics are away today, so could you give us some code to look at (by **editing** your question)?

Comment: The submit button is always make post back - maybe you mean that is not call the function on code behind ? Please give here your code for real help.

Comment: Are you adding the same user control to the page whenever any postback occur?

Comment: Have you "registered" `btnSave_Click` as the handler for the click event?  Can you show us the button from the `.ascx` markup? (Not rendered HTML, but the source markup)

Comment: yes i ahev done it, see the code above

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You added your control too late.

If you want to be be accept a button click, your user control should be added before loadComplete. Ideally you should add it `Init`, or if it depends on some input, add it on the `Load` event.

If you are adding your control on something like a button click event, it will render just fine. But you will not receive any events on that control.

Your event target (set in a hidden element in html), is evaluated after LoadComplete. 
If your control does not exist when this is evaluated it will not receive the event.

What you got to understand is that, grid's ItemCommand event fired once, it will not fire on the next `PostBack`. You need to remember that you have added that control, and add it back on every `PostBack` again till you need it to be there. The best place to remember this is the `ViewState`.

You should set a variable in `ViewState` that indicates that you are currently showing that particular control and use that variable to add the control on `Load`. You cannot do it on `Init` cause ViewState is not avaliable on Init.

Comment: But how to fix it on load event, i am adding control on grid's ItemCommand event

Comment: See edited answer. You need to keep track of such control additions. Asp.net adds all the controls needed to the control collection on every request.

Comment: I will also mention, that you might find it simpler to always add the control and show and hide it when needed using its `Visible` property.